# csv contains HTML while exporting that file in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to perform functions exporting and importing CSV file.
I have done importing file successfully, but while exporting file, the downloaded CSV file contains HTML code with header, body and footer. I think that was from `default.ctp`, not sure.

Why, and from where, is that code automatically embedded ?

```
<?php function export()
    {
            $fp = NULL;
            $results = NULL;
            $row = NULL;        
            $results = $this->Order->find('all',array('fields'=> array('Order.sku','Order.inventory')));
            $fp = fopen('php://output','w+');
            $filename = "results.csv"; 
            header('Content-type: application/csv');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment;');
            fputcsv($fp,array(
            'sku',
            'inventory'
            ));
            $ctr = count($results);
            print($ctr);
            foreach($results as $row) 
            {
                fputcsv($fp,array(
                $row['Order']['sku'],
                $row['Order']['inventory']
                ));
            }
          fclose($fp);

    } ?>
```

Comment: what cake version are u using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable layout rendering, stick this in your controller action:

```
$this->autoRender = false;
```

Tehnichally, this is not the correct way to do CSV, you should create a CSV layout and view, but if it works, ce le vie.

Answer (score 1):

Thats a simple solution, either create a CSV layout that contains the necessary headers, or just use the built in ajax layout:

```
$this->layout = 'ajax';
```

In your controller action. That should fix it for you.

Comment: This might not work as OP doesn't seem to be passing anything to a view.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what he is doing.. What file does this export() function reside in?

Answer (score 0):

Disable layout in controller

```
<?php

$this->layout=null;

?>
```